# What's the difference between svg() and devSVG()?

Tags: r, svg, graph, adobe-illustrator, inkscape

What is the difference between `svg()` and `devSVG()` of of the `RSvgDevice` package? I have trouble imprting plots of svg() into Illustrator but plots of RSvgDevice seem to work fine. Inkscape seems to work with both fine. Is there a difference in the implementation?

Where is the difference in the plots produced? There also seems to be a difference in the size of the files produced.

```
library(MASS)
library(vcd)
library(RSvgDevice)

#70 kb file
        svg("test.svg.svg", width = 10, height = 10)
        data("PreSex")
        fm <- loglm(~ PremaritalSex + ExtramaritalSex +Gender + MaritalStatus,data = PreSex)
        plot(fm, split_vertical = TRUE)
        dev.off()
#7 kb file 
        devSVG("test.Rsvg.svg", width = 10, height = 10)
        data("PreSex")
        fm <- loglm(~ PremaritalSex + ExtramaritalSex +Gender + MaritalStatus,data = PreSex)
        plot(fm, split_vertical = TRUE)
        dev.off()
```

Comment: Open the files in a text editor and you'll see.

Comment: your comment sounds more like a prophecy than an answer..."say i must"....